# Usage of "come"

Tags: word-usage

Can I exchange the sentence " How do they come packaged" with "How do they packaged"?
What is the function of the word "come"?

Answer (score 1):

> "How do they come packaged?"

Because of the word *packaged*, the verb *come* in this context aligns with Definition #5 in NOAD:

> **come** (*v.*) be sold, available, or found in a specified form : *the cars come with a variety of extras* | *they come in three*

Your suggested alternate wording is close:

> How **are** they packaged?

means essentially the same thing (you need to use *are*, instead of *do*).

---

Had you not used the word *packaged*, though, the situation would change slightly:

> "How do they come?"

could be changed to:

> "How will they arrive?"

This aligns with Definition #1 in NOAD:

> **come** (*v.*) arrive at a specified place : *my trunk hasn't come yet*

Answer (score 0):

Most often the usage they **come packaged** *complete with* batteries and manual is used to indicate additional items that are included while they **are** packed in sets of three is used to indicate groupings and they **will arrive** packed in plain brown paper indicates the style of packaging.  *Note that the last of these implies that the content would cause embarrassment if identifiable from the packaging.*